# Android bitmap color confusion

Tags: android, bitmap

i have i png-image in my drawable-xhdpi folder, its 32x32 pixels in size:

[image]
When i created the image i used exactly two colors.

When i load the image as a bitmap, loop trough it and print each color value in the logcat i see more than two different color values:

```
renderSystem.addSprite(R.drawable.walltest, 0, 2);
```

In rendersystem:

```
public void addSprite(int id, int x, int y) {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);
    printColors(image);
    //active.add(new Sprite(image, worldToScreenX(x), worldToScreenY(y)));
}


private void printColors(Bitmap src) {
    for (int i = 0; i < src.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.getHeight(); j ++) {
            Log.d("Color", String.valueOf(src.getPixel(i,j)));
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
09-19 13:03:38.832 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller I/chatty: uid=10082(u0_a82) com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller identical 36 lines
09-19 13:03:38.832 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -7975603
09-19 13:03:38.832 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -10734540
09-19 13:03:38.832 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -16777216
09-19 13:03:38.832 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -16777216
09-19 13:03:38.832 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -11325392
09-19 13:03:38.832 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -7975603
09-19 13:03:38.832 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller I/chatty: uid=10082(u0_a82) com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller identical 8 lines
09-19 13:03:38.832 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -7975603
09-19 13:03:38.851 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -10734540
09-19 13:03:38.857 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller I/chatty: uid=10082(u0_a82) com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller identical 9 lines
09-19 13:03:38.857 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -10734540
09-19 13:03:38.857 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -12639196
09-19 13:03:38.857 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -16777216
09-19 13:03:38.860 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller I/chatty: uid=10082(u0_a82) com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller identical 41 lines
09-19 13:03:38.860 2576-2576/com.example.benjamin.dungeondweller D/Color: -16777216
```

This tells me that the bitmap image does not have the same colors as the source png image. Why is that? And how do i load an exact replica in bitmap format?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your bitmap was filtered while creating. Check individual RGB values of the pixels and see the little difference there.

Comment: How do i disable filtering?

Comment: Nevermind, i created an bitmapfactory options and set inscaled to true. Now it works.